# Typescript VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have Visual studio 2013 Ultimate, and want to use typescript. I installed the plug-in: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

It didn't show any errors during or after the install. When I started VS2013 again and went to File > New > Project, there was a TypeScript thing in the templates. But it said "Install the latest TypeScript for Visual Studio", and trying to create such a 'project' results in a "project creation failed" message.

I also tried making a new file, but there was nothing related to typescript. Making a new file and changing the extension to .ts didn't work either (the icon of the file shows that it's an unknown filetype).

How do I get typescript to work in VS2013?

EDIT: I noticed that there's no typescript listed in de list of installed extensions. Could it be that the plug-in didn't detect my VS2013?

Comment: It sounds like you've done the right things. (That's what I've done to get it working on various machines.) You may want to try uninstalling and then reinstalling . . . ?

Comment: I already tried that, but I'll try it again...

Comment: I restarted after reinstalling, and now it shows the typescript template. But VS crashes whenever I try to open/create a typescript project.

Comment: My best guess is that something is wonky with your VS install. You could try disabling all your installed add-ins (especially WebEssentials), and/or try reinstalling VS. Sorry, no ideas beyond that.

Comment: That fixed it. I disabled Web Essentials 2013, restarted and everything worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question based on the comments on the question and own experiences. For when other people find this question.

It helps to restart your computer after installing the typescript plug-in.

And the Web Essensials 2013 plug-in doesn't mix well with typescript, so disable that to avoid Visual Studio crashing. (credit to Ken Smith; see comments on question).

Comment: This is mentioned in the changelog.. http://vswebessentials.com/changelog rtfm ;-)

Comment: I hope you forgive me for not reading every changelog for everything I install...

Comment: I am using WebEssentials, it provides nice TypeScript integration, never had any problems.